# Create a dotted line status bar during a process

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a status bar that runs during a rsync process. This is the code I tried. but this just keeps a creating a dotted line that never ends. I thought it would end when the rsync ended?

```
while (rsync -r /Volumes/foo /Volumes/bar) ; do
echo -n  "."
done
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Also, have you considered `rsync --progress ...` instead of trying to write your own replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that the `while` command cannot work. You need to learn in which order expressions of a program getting executed and how control structures work.

Fortunately `rsync` has it's own way to show progress. Use this:

```
rsync --progress -r /Volumes/foo /Volumes/bar
```

---

I should not do this, because you have to learn programming, but here comes a hack how to achieve this:

```
rsync --progress -r /Volumes/foo /Volumes/bar | awk '{printf "."}'
```

I'm using `awk` to replace every line of `rsync's` progress output by a `.`. This is not exact, as there are more than one output line for each file. But it should do a good job unless you are counting the dots. You can try to refine it.. (for learning :)

Comment: i know progress this is not helpful

Comment: The `while` will execute the rsync again and again. (of course) You get one `.` per rsync run

Comment: It's hard to answer you. It would be helpful if you would have at least a minimal understanding of programming.

Comment: Is there a way I can do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: thats what I'm trying to do. thats why I'm trying to make a simple dotted line, while a process runs. Its all about learning.